# How can i find the income statement for the companies a company owns

Tags: income-statement

For example, Facebook owns Oculus. How can I see how much money Oculus is making?

Comment: If Oculus shares are not publicly traded, it’s voluntary to publish this information. FB might or might not decide to give any information.